# On scroll loading Mask EXT JS

Tags: extjs, aem

I am trying to apply an enhancement on below code line. If anyone knows solution, please help me!

```
loaderMask = new CQ.Ext.LoadMask(CQ.Ext.getBody(), { msg:"Loading... Please wait"})
loaderMask.show();
```

This loader mask is fixed in the page position and I like to fix it on the user screen while user scrolls up or down on the page.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

That would be:

```
 scrollPanel.getScrollable().on('scrollstart', function(){
    scrollPanel.mask({message: 'scrolling'});
 });
 scrollPanel.getScrollable().on('scrollend', function(){
    scrollPanel.unmask();
 });
```

But it sounds more like, you are loading data and while loading you want to mask the container. If so you might want to listen to the beforeLoad and load event of the store and mask and unmask while it is loading.

The alternative is to use databinding to the store.loading.
If you want to know more about that, please setup a fiddle (fiddle.sencha.com).